# How do you invalidate an ASP.Net Web API 2 Bearer token?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I would like to forcibly invalidate a Bearer Token that was issued by the default ApplicationOAuthProvider from the ASP.Net Web API2 project template.

The project has the below code, which doesn't work for Bearer tokens.

```
Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
```

Comment: You do this by storing tokens hashes and blacklisting them. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58347757/631527

Answer (score 10):

There's nothing built in for that - you could build your own mechanism for it which typically involves something like a database check on each request.

The other thing is, keep token lifetime short and use something like refresh tokens - see here:
http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/15/adding-refresh-tokens-to-a-web-api-v2-authorization-server/

Comment: Many thanks. I think building my own mechanism would be best. I've noticed that generating another bearer token invalidates the previous one. So part of the logoff procedure could simply create another token that isn't returned to the user.

Comment: Not sure how you observed that behavior - but i cannot confirm that.

Comment: @Theo, "generating another bearer token invalidates the previous one". That's not the default behavior of Bearer Tokens since they validate the token based on user info and system date. If they match those criteria, they are valid.

Comment: crazy, i can't know which are the authorized apps and no way to disable them, what were they thinking?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm in the exact same situation currently and refuse to believe they didn't think of this issue when coding identity for web api's.